# jasmine regexp using toContain function

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am using [jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) for testing JavaScript code.
I would like to check the content of render function in this way:

```
expect(this.view.el.innerHTML).toContain('<a href="#link">'+ 'regexp(any text)' +'</a>');
```

would be possible to pass some parameter as a regular expression?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 7):

I think you would need to use the `toMatch` matcher which takes a regular expression (`toContain` expects a string parameter) and build your regular expression by concatenating the fixed and variable strings something like this:

```
var searchString = ...
expect(innerHTML).toMatch(new RegExp('<a href="#link">' + searchString + '</a>'));
```